# Flag 200h open file

Tags: c++

```
cseg01:00056938                 mov     edx, offset var_byte_0004DCC8
cseg01:0005693D                 mov     eax, offset hmi_drv_str
cseg01:00056942                 call    strcpy_
cseg01:00056947                 mov     edx, offset aHmidrv_386 ; "hmidrv.386"
cseg01:0005694C                 mov     eax, offset hmi_drv_str
cseg01:00056951                 call    strcat_
cseg01:00056956                 push    200h
cseg01:0005695B                 mov     eax, offset hmi_drv_str
cseg01:00056960                 push    eax
cseg01:00056961                 call    open_
```

```
cseg01:00056966                 add     esp, 8
cseg01:00056969                 mov     [ebp+var_4], eax
cseg01:0005696C                 cmp     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
cseg01:00056970                 jnz     short loc_5697E
cseg01:00056972                 mov     [ebp+var_14], 0Fh
cseg01:00056979                 jmp     on_exit
cseg01:0005697E ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:0005697E
cseg01:0005697E loc_5697E:                              ; CODE XREF: Unkn_Subroutine_Reg_7+8Dj
cseg01:0005697E                 mov     ebx, 2Ch ; ','
cseg01:00056983                 mov     edx, offset unk_C7F78
cseg01:00056988                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
cseg01:0005698B                 call    read_
```

This code trying to open file of sound manager for MS- DOS hmidrv.386, but please help understand what means flag 200h?

Answer (score 1):

In DOS/Windows this is the constant value for `O_TRUNC`, used to erase the file's content and place the cursor (`seek`) at offset 0.

`.386` extension is used by DOS and earlier versions of Windows for virtual device drivers.

Truncating this type of "file" has no effect, and of course there is nothing to `read()` from a file that has just been emptied.

The most likely explanation for this code sequence is that the program you're looking at expects a *device driver* to exist by this name and that reading from it returns some data.

However, this driver may not be available in the particular system.

Then, if there happens to be a regular file named `hmidrv.386`, the program will read from it, expecting the driver initial data but get whatever is inside the (regular) file instead, which may yield unexpected results.

*Truncate* before read ensures that the data read, if any, cannot be a normal file content.

Comment: I updated code in question, I put more code, in code we can see - next after "open" is "read". How we can read truncated file? i.e. file opened with O_TRUNC flag? If file is truncated, it has set zero data. What we read- zero data? And moreover this file we open - hmidrv.386 - it is music driver to play sound. It driver plays sound in this app, it is needed to reproduce sound in this app, why need truncate this file?

Comment: use dosbox debugger to step through and test if the file really gets truncated

Comment: Is the implementation of the `open_` function part of the code? DOS extensions can make virtual devices available as files. Early versions of Windows use *.386 files for this purpose. If this is the case then the truncate flag has no effect, but should there be a regular file by that name it will be truncated. It may have been added by a compiler: calling `fopen` with "w" mode implies `O_TRUNC` on the underlying `open` call